# What can cause gnome-terminal, invoked without --disable-factory, to block?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, codeblocks, gnome-terminal

We are running gnome-terminal from a script as follows:

```
gnome-terminal -t 'Program Console' -x telnet 10.1.1.50 3000
```

The telnet command causes a command-line program to be run on the remote computer and the output is displayed in the gnome-terminal.

When this script is run from version 10.05 of the Code::Blocks IDE running on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, this works as expected: the gnome-terminal command does not block the script.

However, when it is run from Code::Blocks version 13.12 (on another installation of) Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, it does block.  If, instead of clicking on the Code::Blocks icon in the Gnome Launcher, Code::Blocks 13.12 is invoked from a gnome-terminal outside of Code::Blocks, it does not block.

I want to know what could cause gnome-terminal invoked without --disable-factory to block.  We've strace'd gnome-terminal, looked at the process, group and session IDs using:

```
ps -eo user,pid,ppid,ruid,rgid,euid,egid,suid,sgid,sess,cmd --forest
```

I can't see any significant difference to the IDs, but I can see that when gnome-terminal does not block, the telnet command is in a different process tree from Code::Blocks.

According to the man page, gnome-terminal contacts the activation name server, unless --disable-factory is used, so perhaps Code::Blocks 13.12 is doing something which prevents the gnome-terminal from contacting the name server.  I can't find any information about the name server online, apart from references to the gnome-terminal man page.

Does anyone know what could be causing gnome-terminal to block?

I mentioned --disable-factory, because we've used --disable-factory elsewhere, and that always causes gnome-terminal to block until the command it is executing completes.

Here's the output of ps (unimportant lines deleted) when the telnet command blocks (Code::Blocks version 13.12, invoked from Gnome Launcher):

```
USER       PID  PPID  RUID  RGID  EUID  EGID  SUID  SGID  SESS CMD
1000      3413     1  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2853 gnome-terminal
1000      3417  3413  1000  1000  1000    43  1000    43  2853  \_ gnome-pty-helper
1000      3418  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  3418  \_ bash
1000      3495  3418  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  3418  |   \_ minicom
1000      3567  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  3567  \_ bash
1000      5189  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  5189  \_ bash
1000      8669  5189  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  5189  |   \_ gtodo
1000     16384  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 16384  \_ bash
1000     18195  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 18195  \_ bash
1000     20713  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 20713  \_ bash
1000     23255 20713  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 20713      \_ vi gnome-terminal-query-2
1000     23492 20713  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 20713      \_ ps -eo user,pid,ppid,ruid,rgid,euid,egid,suid,sgid,sess,cmd --forest
1000     23268     1  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2853 codeblocks
1000     23482 23268  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2853  \_ /bin/sh ./gdb-switcher -nx -fullname -quiet -args /storage/work/c/a/s/d/telnet_run_platform.sh
1000     23483 23482  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2853      \_ /bin/sh ./telnet_debug_platform.sh
1000     23485 23483  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2853          \_ gnome-terminal -t Program Console -x telnet 10.1.1.50 3000
1000     23489 23485  1000  1000  1000    43  1000    43  2853              \_ gnome-pty-helper
1000     23490 23485  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 23490              \_ telnet 10.1.1.50 3000
```

and here's the output when we run codeblocks from a gnome-terminal:

```
USER       PID  PPID  RUID  RGID  EUID  EGID  SUID  SGID  SESS CMD
1000      3413     1  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  2853 gnome-terminal
1000      3417  3413  1000  1000  1000    43  1000    43  2853  \_ gnome-pty-helper
1000      3418  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  3418  \_ bash
1000      3495  3418  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  3418  |   \_ minicom
1000      3567  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  3567  \_ bash
1000      5189  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  5189  \_ bash
1000      8669  5189  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  5189  |   \_ gtodo
1000     16384  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 16384  \_ bash
1000     18195  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 18195  \_ bash
1000     20713  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 20713  \_ bash
1000     23255 20713  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 20713  |   \_ vi gnome-terminal-query-2
1000     23936 20713  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 20713  |   \_ ps -eo user,pid,ppid,ruid,rgid,euid,egid,suid,sgid,sess,cmd --forest
1000     23686  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 23686  \_ bash
1000     23748 23686  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 23686  |   \_ codeblocks
1000     23924 23748  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 23686  |       \_ /usr/local/bin/gdb -nx -fullname -quiet -args /storage/work/c/a/s/d/telnet_run_platform.sh
1000     23931  3413  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 23931  \_ telnet 10.1.1.50 3000
```

(The script gdb-switcher, which we invoke from Code::Blocks, goes on to exec gdb, so that's why codeblocks has this process as a child when the gnome-terminal command does not block.)

Comment: I don't know why you think `--disable-factory` is involved here. Does one of the invocations contain that and not the other? That seems to be a (very very poorly named) option for controlling whether `gnome-terminal` spawns a new window or not when one already exists. I think that is unrelated to the issue. Can you show the `ps` forest for the two different invocation methods?

Comment: I've added a note to expain why --disable-factory is relevant and I've added ps output for both Code::Blocks 13.12 invocations.

Comment: Ah. Ok then. It sounds like this blocks when gnome-terminal doesn't use an existing window/session and doesn't block when it does. That makes some sense (and explains why `--disable-factory` would change things). Which makes it sound like you want to ensure that you always have gnome-terminal running already and the new instance is able to contact the `activation name server`.